# Prove that for $m_i >0$ $\frac{n \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m_i}}{\sum^{n}_{i=1}m_i}< 1$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $m_i >0$ for all $i=1,...,n$ 
How can I prove that 
$\frac{n \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m_i}}{\sum^{n}_{i=1}m_i} < 1$?

Comment: Taking $m_1 = 0.5, m_2 = 0.5$ is a counter example

Comment: I think you can conclude with Jensens inequality that 
$$
\frac{n}{\sum_i m_i} \leq \frac{\sum_i 1/m_i}{n}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the $m_i=m$,
the expression is
$\frac{n^2/m}{nm}
=\frac{n}{m^2}
$ which can take any value
by choosing $m$
appropriately.

So the inequality is false.